# Unable to login GUI using credentials in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: server, 22.04, ssh, login

Unable to login to GUI in Ubuntu 22.04 using the correct credentials, getting error as

> Sorry, password Authentication didn't work, please try again.

When try to login from putty, username was getting in brackets, not sure how to fix the issue. Please provide the solution.

```
root@localhost:~$ ssh 10.10.120.36
(root@192.168.6.112) Password:
```

Need help to fix

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] with the full error screen

Comment: Error snap was attached, please check

Comment: If your computer gets credentials from the network, you could contact your administrator for help troubleshooting

Comment: How the server will get credentials from network side, which credentials need to check with network team

Comment: can i disable network and try to login?? will it work?

Comment: Just tell them you think LDAP login isn't working for you. Disabling network probably won't work, just like going into a company building and unplugging the Internet doesn't give you access to all the compters

Comment: i am trying to login as a local user,  that also not working

Comment: You could try resetting the local password with https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/1004020 if you're allowed to. If you still can't get in, use the `init=/bin/bash` trick to boot and look in `/var/log` for detail about the earlier failures